# Jquery Google CDN not recognised when loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cdn, modernizr

I have been trying to load the Jquery 3.1.1 Google CDN using Modernizr, throught the following code:

```
Modernizr.load([
        {
            load: "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js",
            complete: function () {
                if(!window.jQuery){
                    Modernizr.load("_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js");
                }
            }
        },
```

I have correctly installed Modernizr, and I am certain that the api is correct, yet it will not load, and the console say's that it can't find it. I would appreciate it if you could suggest a solution.

Thanks,

Milo

(Update: I am using Modernizr 2.8, so it supports Modernizr.load)

Comment: What, exactly, does the console say?

Comment: It says cannot find file

Comment: Which version are you using? In Modernizr 3.x this method is complety deprecated (even with yepnope).

Comment: Modernizr 2.8.3

Comment: any luck if you give full url ,`https://ajax.....`

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Comment: @Milo.D What is the URL of the file it can't find? Can you show a screenshot? Are you able to access `ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js` directly?

Answer (score 0):

```
Note: Modernizr <=2.7.1 are working fine with load method call.
Except: 2.5b verison alone.

Modernizr.load({
  load: [
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js'    
             ],
  complete: function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
      Modernizr.load({
        load: [ '_js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js' ],
        complete : function(){ 
                alert('Loaded jQuery: _js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js');                    
        }});
    } else {
    alert('Loaded jQuery: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js');
    }
  }
});
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/stram1986/7mbzv804/)